# Ruby FileUtils.mv: Error file not found

Tags: ruby

The following piece of code should iterate over a directory list replacing the old directory name with the new one. However, the `FileUtils.mv` call returns no such file or directory.

I have added the line `File.exists?` which returns true for all paths passed to it via this loop

```
Dir["projects/*/*/old"].each{|dir|
    Dir.chdir dir
    Dir.chdir "../"
    puts File.exists?("#{Dir.pwd }/old")
    FileUtils.mv "#{Dir.pwd }/old", "#{Dir.pwd }/new_path"
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a folder match as well. Because, `File.exists? 'folder'` returns `true` as well.

See if you have any folders with the name `old`.

```
# This will list all directories with a name "old"
find . -name old -type d
```

Comment: Yeah, there's no file called old, only a directory. `File.exists?` works for both directories and files.